# Unable to connect to socket.io from Android client the server requires 'query'

Tags: android, socket.io

I'm trying to connect to socket.io from an Android app/client, but I keep getting the following error

io.socket.engineio.client.EngineIOException: xhr poll error

From the server side, (as the back end guy stated), this is the code of the connection

```
var socket = require('socket.io-client')('https://al3malh-geniusescode.c9users.io:8081', {
query: {
    "session_key": '52c3cf92-34d8-4edd-8809-94679533a1c6'
}
});

socket.on('connection', function () {});
```

---

from the android side, (in onCreate method of the activity holding the code) the code is :

---

```
public Socket socket;
IO.Options options = new IO.Options();

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();



 try {
            jsonObject.put("session_key",readFromPreferences(MyApplication.getAppContext(), MyApplication.SESSION_KEY, ""));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

        options.query = jsonObject.toString();

{
            try {

            socket = IO.socket("https://al3malh-geniusescode.c9users.io:8081",options);



        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {
@Override
public void call(Object... args) {

    Log.d("ActivityName: ", "CONNECTION");
}
});

    socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECTING, new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {

            Log.d("ActivityName: ", "Trying To Connect");


        }
    });

    socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECTING, new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {

            Log.d("ActivityName: ", "Trying To Connect");


        }
    });



    socket.on("on_error", new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {

            Log.d("ActivityName: ", "ERROR FROM SERVER"+args[0].toString());

        }
    });
    socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR,new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {

            Log.d("ActivityName: ", args[0].toString());

        }
    });
    socket.connect();
```

---

The library I'm using, is

'io.socket:socket.io-client:0.7.0'

and the permission (INTERNET) is there in the manifest.

Is the problem from the query that I'm passing as string in (Options.query)?

Any help will be highly apprtiated, Thanks in Advance

Comment: Could you add the LogCat of the error?

Comment: Actually the error in the question is caught from  the emitter listener for EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR event from the socket.@Jj